# target search in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

In MS Excel there is a tool for an iterative calculation of one cell given a condition in an other connected cell (target search is my obvisoly very poor translation from Swedish). I now want to do this whatever-it-is-called in MS Access. Any hint or at least a correct English term would be of great help.

Comment: can you provide an example of what you are doing in excel? That should help ease any translation issues

Comment: Oh, and what version of Access/Excel are you using?

Comment: I guess you need VBA and Do Until or Do While. It is possible to use Excel functions from Access, but I am not sure if that is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

target search is called **goal seek** Excel

Answer (score 2):

Well, my advice is not to try to do that in Access! Let Excel do the Excel stuff (such as dealing with this 'Goal seek' algorythm), and let Access do the Access stuff: tables, views, relations, queries, data integrity, foreign keys, etc. And if your data is under Access, have it exported to Excel first!